# Difference between Critical and orbital velocity

Tags: orbital-motion, terminology, earth, satellites

What is the difference between orbital and critical velocity of satallite ?
I have read that critical velocity is constant value and it does not depend upon altitude. It only gives the velocity of smallest possible orbit given that there is no friction and retarding forces. At other place I read that critical velocity is also called orbital velocity as it gives velocity to put satallite into stable orbit around earth. Are the two terms same??

Comment: @Eagle the critical velocity disambiguation page you link is utterly unhelpful in this context...

Comment: @KyleOman Yeah thanks for pointing out. I hadn't checked it